# How do I create an NSURL with a nil absoluteString?

Tags: nsurl, foundation

[`NSURL.absoluteString` is a `nullable` property](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurl/1409868-absolutestring). How do I create an `NSURL` with a `nil` `absoluteString`?

Comment: Interesting.  That's a change from Xcode 7/iOS 9/Swift 2.2.  (`var absoluteString: String { get }`)

Comment: The [comment](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/730ccd46d6b4dcb7a2f09927645aa291a55528bb/Foundation/URL.swift#L521-L523) in swift-corelibs-foundation above that method says "NSURL (really CFURL, which provides its implementation) has quite a few quirks".  The implementation simply returns the NSURL `.absoluteString`, so whoever wrote the Swift wrapper thinks it can never be nil.